# How to automate createsuperuser on django?

Tags: django

I want to automatically run `manage.py createsuperuser` on django but it seems that there is no way of setting a default password.

How can I get this? It has to be independent on the django database.

Comment: have you looked into just saving your created superuser a fixture and loading it using manage.py?

Comment: @turbotux Hendrik F answer takes a similar approach to what you suggest, with the added ability to read the values (login, password...) from env vars (or filesystem, ...). I would highly suggest going this direction instead of the ad-hoc python scripts, which have problems when you restart the application.

Answer (score 221):

As of Django 3.0 you can use default `createsuperuser --noinput` command and set all required fields (including password) as environment variables `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD`, `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME`, `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL` for example. `--noinput` flag is required.

This comes from the original docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser

It is the most convenient way to add `createsuperuser` to scripts and pipelines.

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful, it's perfect to be used with `docker-compose` this answer should be on the top

Comment: this is very important for the docker setup. thanks a ton.

Comment: In the context of Dockerizing Django, this is awesome! Exactly what I was wondering if existed.

Comment: How do you use this with docker compose?

Comment: @PhilO
create new ".env" file  with mentioned environment variables  .
you can  attach the  vars  into your  django  container with  --env-file
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
inside the container run  " python manage.py createsuperuser  --no-input"

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that you can keep environment variables out of public code, which is necessary for security.

Comment: Cool and modern solution! Thanks. Btw, does anybody know if it's possible to crypt the django superuser password in the .env file?

Comment: It does not seem to work with docker-compose, if you want to run an extra command. Even the simplest example seems not to be working ` python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username=admin --email=admin@example.com --password=password `

Comment: @AymanFerki For passing sensitive information, you should rather use secrets: https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/

Answer (score 198):

If you reference *User* directly, your code will not work in projects where the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting has been changed to a different user model. A more generic way to create the user would be:

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@myproject.com', 'password')" | python manage.py shell
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Here there is a simple version of the script to create a superuser:

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')" | python manage.py shell
```

Comment: super useful when trying to create superuser in heroku and your network blocks port 5000

Comment: I would delete the existing superuser, so this is valid for every build:

```echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.filter(email='admin@example.com').delete(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin@example.com', 'admin', 'nimda')" | python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Personally I don't think deleting the user on each build is a good idea. You risk unintentionally deleting any associated records via a cascade delete. A safer option is to simply bail-out if the user already exists (or update the existing User record).

Comment: At least on Django 1.11. the order of the arguments is ('username', 'email', 'pass'), not ('email', 'username', 'pass'). See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` no longer works. Use this:

    `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; 
    User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@myproject.com', 'my secure password')`

Comment: @dcalde thanks for your comment, using [get_user_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) covers more use cases.

Comment: Had to do it without quotes, windows 10 x64 python 3.6 with virtualenv 


`echo from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@myproject.com', 'password') | python manage.py shell`

Comment: I feel a bit bad down-voting this, because I'm sure it was the right answer when it was written. But the question specifically asks about `./manage.py createsuperuser` and it's now possible to do what the OP wants with that tool, as another answer shows.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use the [Data Migration approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53555252/1636885) as suggested by [Hendrik F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53555252/1636885) later: "it naturally addresses the biggest problem of the accepted answer (a migration is applied only once on a deployment, so the user is only created once -> otherwise, you will get the "**User already exists**" error)".

Answer (score 70):

I use './manage.py shell -c':

```
./manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'adminpass')"
```

This doesn't uses an extra echo, this has the benefit that you can pass it to a docker container for execution. Without the need to use **sh -c "..."** which gets you into quote escaping hell.

And remember that **first** comes username, then the email.

If you have a custom user model you need to import that and not `auth.models.User`

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for me, I'm seeing:
`AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'`

Comment: when you have a custom user model like `users.User`  you need to import from that and not from `auth.User`

Answer (score 67):

I was searching for an answer to this myself. I decided to create a Django command which extends the base `createsuperuser` command ([GitHub](https://github.com/adamcharnock/swiftwind-heroku/blob/master/swiftwind_heroku/management/commands/create_superuser_with_password.py)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.management.commands import createsuperuser
from django.core.management import CommandError


class Command(createsuperuser.Command):
    help = 'Crate a superuser, and allow password to be provided'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(
            '--password', dest='password', default=None,
            help='Specifies the password for the superuser.',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        password = options.get('password')
        username = options.get('username')
        database = options.get('database')

        if password and not username:
            raise CommandError("--username is required if specifying --password")

        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)

        if password:
            user = self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get(username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

Example use:

```
./manage.py createsuperuser2 --username test1 --password 123321 --noinput --email 'blank@email.com'
```

This has the advantage of still supporting the default command use, while also allowing non-interactive use for specifying a password.

Comment: I wish the default `createsuperuser` had this `--password` field too

Comment: You could add an example usage: `./manage.py createsuperuser2 --username test1 --password 123321 --noinput --email 'blank@email.com'`

Comment: how is `createsuperuser2` mapped to this class, function

Comment: @SrinathGanesh have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

You need to name the python file `createsuperuser2.py` and place it into the defined directory structure from the link above.

Comment: It's not safe to pass a password through command line. Another user could see the password in process list.

Comment: In order to command createsuperuser2,
1. make "management" folder under random application folder
2. make "commands" folder under the management folder
3. make "createsuperuser2.py" and use the extension code above. 

Refer to the django documentation below for 1) directory structure for custom commands, 2) how to make custom command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 65):

I would suggest running a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), so when migrations are applied to the project, a superuser is created as part of the migrations. The username and password can be setup as environment variables. This is also useful when running an app in a container (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027203/create-django-super-user-in-a-docker-container-without-inputting-password/53261943#53261943) as an example)

Your data migration would then look like this:

```
import os
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('<your_app>', '<previous_migration>'),
    ] # can also be emtpy if it's your first migration

    def generate_superuser(apps, schema_editor):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User

        DJANGO_SU_NAME = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SU_NAME')
        DJANGO_SU_EMAIL = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SU_EMAIL')
        DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD')

        superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username=DJANGO_SU_NAME,
            email=DJANGO_SU_EMAIL,
            password=DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD)

        superuser.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(generate_superuser),
    ]
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**:
Some might raise the question how to set these environment variables and make Django aware of them. There are a lot of ways and it's been answered in other SO posts, but just as a quick pointer, creating a `.env` file is a good idea. You could then use the [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) package, but if you have setup a virtual environment with pipenv, it will automatically set the envvars in your `.env` file. Likewise, running your app via docker-compose can read in your `.env` file.

Comment: **TIP: Please consider this approach**. This is a high quality answer: it naturally leverages built-in functionalities of Django to answer the question instead of echoing ad-hoc python scripts, plus it naturally addresses the biggest problem of the accepted answer (a migration is applied only once on a deployment, so the user is only created once). It works beautifully in a container context.

Comment: This seems a great answer. I still don't know where in the project does this piece of code fit?

Comment: It should be in your migrations folder, e.g `root/⁨mysite⁩/myapp⁩/⁨migrations⁩` - if your read the docs, it explains how you can create an empty migration and modify that `python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname`

Comment: Why do you need the DJANGO_DB_NAME? it is never used.

Comment: You should mention to add the following to load the .env vars to the `settings.py` file:
`python
# loading .env
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

env_path = Path('.', '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
`

Comment: I wanted to make a User if non exist. So I boiled creting superuser down to `superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(username="Admin", password="1234")` no .env required. Answer to different question tho.

Comment: This fails when using a custom user model. After you add this migration you will no longer be able to add columns when using a fresh db.

Comment: In order to get this to work I had to pass `last_login=django.utils.timezone.now()` to create_superuser.

Comment: A high quality answer but this fails on a custom user model, please consider using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` instead of importing this model

Answer (score 43):

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=testuser \
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=testpass \
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL="admin@admin.com" \
python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput
```

[Documentation for the createuser command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser)

Comment: This is the easiest solution. But you can overwrite `noinput` flag with other params: `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=testpass python manage.py createsuperuser --username testuser --email admin@email.com --noinput`

Comment: This method works in *`Django 3.0`* and later not in *`Django 2.2`*

Comment: It doesn't on Django 4.0 you need to pass email. Otherwise you will receive the following error: `CommandError: You must use --email with --noinput.`

Answer (score 21):

You could write a simple python script to handle the automation of superuser creation. The `User` model is just a normal Django model, so you'd follow the normal process of writing a stand-alone Django script. Ex:

```
import django
django.setup()

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

u = User(username='unique_fellow')
u.set_password('a_very_cryptic_password')
u.is_superuser = True
u.is_staff = True
u.save()
```

You can also pass `createsuperuser` a few options, namely `--noinput` and `--username`, which would let you automatically create new superusers, but they would not be able to login until you set a password for them.

Comment: Ok for `cretesuperuser`, but how to set the password then? I would like to do that inside a bash script...

Comment: This is missing the permissions, so user created this way won't get access to the admin site for example.

Answer (score 16):

Current most voted answer:

- Deletes the user if it exists and as noted by @Groady in the comments you risk unintentionally deleting any associated records via a cascade delete.
- Checks superuser existence filtering by mail so if two superusers have the same mail god knows which one it deletes.
- It is cumbersome to update the script parameters: username, password, and mail.
- Does not log what it did.

An improved version would be:

```
USER="admin"
PASS="super_password"
MAIL="admin@mail.com"
script="
from django.contrib.auth.models import User;

username = '$USER';
password = '$PASS';
email = '$MAIL';

if User.objects.filter(username=username).count()==0:
    User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password);
    print('Superuser created.');
else:
    print('Superuser creation skipped.');
"
printf "$script" | python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Much cleaner (better) than the accepted answer. You could also have used: `if not User.objects.filter(username = username).exists()`,

Answer (score 8):

A [solution](https://github.com/hartwork/django-createsuperuserwithpassword) based on [Adam Charnock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764723/adam-charnock)'s approach [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42491469) is available as a Python package by now.  It takes three steps:

1. Install: `pip install django-createsuperuserwithpassword`
2. Activate: `INSTALLED_APPS += ("django_createsuperuserwithpassword", )`
3. Apply:

   ```
    python manage.py createsuperuserwithpassword \
            --username admin \
            --password admin \
            --email admin@example.org \
            --preserve
   ```

That's it.

PS: I'm the author of `django-createsuperuserwithpassword`.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem like this.

wsgi.py file always runs when django project starts. So I run create super user commands in here if it doesn't exist.

```
import os

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', {settings_file})

application = get_wsgi_application()

users = User.objects.all()
if not users:
    User.objects.create_superuser(username="username", email="user@example.com", password="password", is_active=True, is_staff=True)
```

A function can be added here. For example; if this "user1" doesn't exist, add "user1".

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        # The magic line
        User.objects.create_user(username= 'rmx',
                                email='superuser@super.com',
                                password='rmx55',
                                is_staff=True,
                                is_active=True,
                                is_superuser=True
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use for serverless/docker builds the [AppConfig.ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method/event to perform this kind of operations, here's an example:

```py
import logging

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as gettext


class Config(AppConfig):
    name: str = "apps.policy"
    label: str = "policy"
    verbose_name: str = gettext("Policies")

    @classmethod
    def ready(cls):
        user_model = get_user_model()
        log = logging.getLogger(cls.label)

        try:
            if not user_model.objects.filter(username="admin").first():
                log.info("Creating default superuser with user and password: admin")
                user_model.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@admin.admin', 'admin')
        except Exception:
            log.warn(
                "Found an error trying to create the superuser, if you aren't"
                "run the user model migration yet, ignore this message"
            )
```

And when I first start my project in the database I see:

```
2021-06-22 06:19:02 policy/info  Creating default superuser with user and password: admin
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (1 silenced).
June 22, 2021 - 06:19:02
Django version 3.1.12, using settings 'settings.env.default'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8027/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Answer (score 2):

With shell_plus it's much easier actually

```
echo "User.objects.create_superuser('test@test.com', 'test')" | python manage.py shell_plus
```

As others mentioned, with Django 3.0 you can pass the credentials via environment variables. However this approach is much more flexible since it allows you to do any other more complicated task like removing all tests users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used Tk421 one liner but got an error message as: 1) I think I am using a later version of Django (1.10) `Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'` 2) the order of the parameters to create_superuser was wrong.

So I replaced it with:

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.filter(email='admin@example.com', is_superuser=True).delete(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'nimda')" | python manage.py shell
```

and what I as really pleased with is that it works on a heroku deployment as well:

```
heroku run echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.filter(email='admin@example.com', is_superuser=True).delete(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'nimda')" | python manage.py shell
```

This will work nicely repeatedly.  I am using it the beginning of a project so don't worry about the terrible cascaded deletes that might occur later.

I have revisited after some trouble with running this inside local() from fabric.  what seemed to be happening is that the pipe symbol mean that it was getting interpreted locally rather than on heroku.  To sort this I wrapped in the command in quotes.  Then had to used triple double quotes for the python strings inside the single quotes of the whole python command.

```
heroku run "echo 'from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.filter(email="""admin@example.com""", is_superuser=True).delete(); User.objects.create_superuser("""admin""", """admin@example.com""", """nimda""")' | python manage.py shell"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; \
                           User.objects.filter(username='admin1').exists() or \
                           User.objects.create_superuser('admin1',
                           'admin1@example.com', 'admin1')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a superuser in a custom command like this:

```
import os

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management import BaseCommand, call_command

from immo_project import settings


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        call_command('createsuperuser', interactive=False, username='admin', email='test@example.com')
        user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
        user.set_password('password')
        user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy, listen on post syncdb signal and read superuser credentials from a configuration file and apply it.

Check out [django-finalware](https://github.com/un33k/django-finalware), and its predecessor [django-bootup](https://github.com/un33k/django-bootup/) [deprecated]

Comment: the link is not available any more

Comment: It is at: https://github.com/un33k/django-bootup - but this says deprecated in favour of https://github.com/un33k/django-finalware

Answer (score 0):

This small python script could create a normal user or a superuser

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import argparse
import random
import string
import django


def main(arguments):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--username', dest='username', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--email', dest='email', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--settings', dest='settings', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--project_dir', dest='project_dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--password', dest='password', type=str, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--superuser', dest='superuser', action='store_true', required=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    sys.path.append(args.project_dir)
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = args.settings
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    django.setup()

    username = args.username
    email = args.email
    password = ''.join(random.sample(string.letters, 20)) if args.password is None else args.password
    superuser = args.superuser 

    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=args.username)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
    if superuser:
            User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
    else:
        User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

    print password


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

--superuser & --password are not mandatory.

If --superuser is not defined, normal user will be created
If --password is not defined, a random password will be generated

```
    Ex : 
        /var/www/vhosts/PROJECT/python27/bin/python /usr/local/sbin/manage_dja_superusertest.py --username USERNAME --email TEST@domain.tld --project_dir /var/www/vhosts/PROJECT/PROJECT/ --settings PROJECT.settings.env
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I cobbled together for Heroku [post_deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#scripts) and a predefined [app.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) variable:

```
if [[ -n "$CREATE_SUPER_USER" ]]; then
    echo "==> Creating super user"
    cd /app/example_project/src
    printf "from django.contrib.auth.models import User\nif not User.objects.exists(): User.objects.create_superuser(*'$CREATE_SUPER_USER'.split(':'))" | python /app/example_project/manage.py shell
fi
```

With this you can have a single env variable:

```
CREATE_SUPER_USER=admin:admin@example.com:password
```

I like the [shell --command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-shell-command) option, but not sure how the get newline character in the command script. Without the newline the `if` expression results in syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py shell < mysite/create_superuser.py`

mysite/create_superuser.py

```
from decouple import config
from django.db import IntegrityError

# getting name,email & password from env variables
DJANGO_SU_NAME = config('DJANGO_SU_NAME')
DJANGO_SU_EMAIL = config('DJANGO_SU_EMAIL')
DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD = config('DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD')

try:
    superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
        username=DJANGO_SU_NAME,
        email=DJANGO_SU_EMAIL,
        password=DJANGO_SU_PASSWORD)
    superuser.save()
except IntegrityError:
    print(f"Super User with username {DJANGO_SU_NAME} is already present")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: More specifically!!!
In docker-compose.yml file under django project container:

command: > /bin/bash -c "python manage.py shell < mysite/create_superuser.py"

Answer (score 0):

For those who just want to host a django website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (even without docker) and are stuck on the superuser part, create a file called ***01_migrate.sh in .platform > hooks > postdeploy*** and input the below:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && { python migrate.py createsuperuser --noinput; }
```

You can then add DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD, DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME, DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL to the configuration section of the application environment.

Then add the below to the folder ***.ebextentions > django.config***

```
container_commands:
    01_chmod1:
         command: "chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_migrate.sh"
```

That will create your superuser in a secure way, with the same logic you can also run migrations and collectstatic by adding to the 01_migrate.sh file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31361735)

Answer (score 0):

### send command to docker-compose

almost same answer like [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577137/11082758).

```bash
docker-compose exec service_name sh -c "
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


username = \"admin\"
email = \"admin@example.com\"
password = \"password\"
User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
"
```

I do not mentioned about validate or check user before creation. if you care about that, check above answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we are automating with some bash, docker, helm, we were having some issues escaping some commas and quotes, after some try/error we figured out the easiest way (easiest for us), this single [line command based on the doc shared previously did the trick](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser)

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=12345 DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=pacho DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=pacho@gmail.com python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found also also personally used is following:

`echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.filter(username='username').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('username', 'email@mail.com','passswordd' )" | python manage.py shell`

All other specified solutions above gave me error that user already exists. I am using this as a shell script to run when even i deploy me new Django API on Kubernetes.

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 only the password goes in as an environment variable, the username and email are accepted as parameters e.g.

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD="foofoofoo"
python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username ian --email "foo@bar.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to command prompt and type:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install django-createsuperuser
Collecting django-createsuperuser
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/8c/344c6367afa62b709adebee039d09229675f1ee34d424180fcee9ed857a5/django-createsuperuser-2019.4.13.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Django>1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from django-createsuperuser) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from django-createsuperuser) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Django>1.0->django-createsuperuser) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Django>1.0->django-createsuperuser) (2018.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: django-createsuperuser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-createsuperuser ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Arif Khan\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\0c\96\2a\e73e95bd420e844d3da1c9d3e496c92642a4f2181535440db2
Successfully built django-createsuperuser
Installing collected packages: django-createsuperuser
```

if not executed the migration then go to django application folder and execute following

1. python manage.py migrate
2. python manage.py createsuperuser

then bingo.