# Django create superuser from batch file

Tags: django, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a batch file that runs syncdb to create a database file, and then create a superuser with the username "admin" and the password "admin".

My code so far:

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
python manage.py createsuperuser --username admin --email admin@exmaple.com 
python manage.py runserver
```

Now this prompts me to enter a password and then confirm the password. Can I enter this information with a command from the same batch file, another batch file, or is this just not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244382/how-to-automate-createsuperuser-on-django

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As it seems you can't provide a password with the `echo ''stuff | cmd`, the only way I see to do it is to create it in Python:

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')" | python manage.py shell
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it is still prompting me for a password as if the echo did not feed it.

Comment: My mistake, it's probably impossible since it's a password. I have updated my answer with something else you can try

Comment: I wonder when they will change this mess, would be nice to do this properly one day

Comment: This gotta be most useful hack for testing python app at initial state

Answer (score 24):

As of Django 3.0 (per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser)) you can use the `createsuperuser --no-input` option and set the password with the `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD` environment variable, e.g.,

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=my_password ./manage.py createsuperuser \
    --no-input \
    --username=my_user \
    --email=my_user@domain.com
```

or, using all environment variables:

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=my_password \
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=my_user \
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=my_user@domain.com \
./manage.py createsuperuser \
--no-input
```

Comment: It should be DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME

Answer (score 1):

And if as is good practice you are using a custom user (CustomUser in this case)

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; CustomUser = get_user_model();  CustomUser.objects.create_superuser('me', 'nt@example.co.uk', 'mypwd')" | python manage.py shell
```