# How would I go about creating a gui to run a django project?

Tags: django, user-interface, exe, executable

I have a Django project and I would like to create a simple python GUI to allow users to change the host address and port on the go without having to interact with a command prompt. I already have a simple python user interface but how would I go about coding something in python that would be able to run a command such as `python manage.py createsuperuser` and fill in the required information without a need to run it in a python script that just calls regular terminal commands such as:

```
subprocess.call(["python","manage.py", "createsuperuser"])
```

I don't know if this is something one can do without commands but would be amazing if it is since then I can just implement it into my basic python GUI that would allow users to `createsuperuser`, `runserver`, `makemigrations`, `migrate` and even change the default host and port on the go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use from this code and change each command you want , pay attention if you run this command your shell must be in your django project folder 
if you want, you can change direction with "CD" command before django run command

```
from subprocess import Popen

from sys import stdout, stdin, stderr

Popen('python manage.py runserver', shell=True, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout ,stderr=stderr)
```

you can communicate with shell by this code :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

from sys import stdout, stdin, stderr

process = Popen('python manage.py createsuperuser', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE ,stderr=stderr)

outs, errs = process.communicate(timeout=15)
print(outs) 

username="username"

process.stdin.write(username.encode('ascii'))

process.stdin.close
```

Unfortunately, for createsuperuser you get this error :

> Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually

You can't create super user with tty for **security problems.**

I prefer :

you can use from this code in your project for create superuser

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User; 
User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')
```

if you want create super user with shell I would suggest running a Data Migration [stackoverflow.com/a/53555252/9533909](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53555252/9533909)

Comment: This is still similar to `subprocess.call(["python","manage.py", "runserver"])` which does more or less the same thing from what I understand. I don't know how I would go about filling in the rest of the information if I wanted to run a `createsuperuser` command from within a python script since it would wait for input after executing. Or can this method help with that?

Comment: Going to try work with this knowledge. It's given me some new ideas but I think for now maybe I can just do the createsuperuser manually like suggested. But at least I can work with this for the other ones that wouldn't have these problems. Thank you :)