# Running Django's createsuperuser in Google Cloud Run

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to run a Django app on Google Cloud Run. The site itself works nicely, can run migrations and collect static assets via a startup script. The one thing I cannot figure out how to do is create a superuser. This requires interactively typing in a password or at least setting it via a django shell. I currently cannot figure out how to do this and it seems like it might not be possible; which would make Cloud Run unusable for Django. Has anyone been able to achieve this or have a sustainable workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Configure the container in Docker at your desktop. Deploy the modified container to Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Django Shell use the [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244382/how-to-automate-createsuperuser-on-django) to create the superuser. Once you have the script make it part of the container build process.