# How to automate create or update of superuser in Django?

Tags: django

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244382/how-to-automate-createsuperuser-on-django), I see that it's possible to update the creation of superusers in Django using:

```sh
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@myproject.com', 'password')" | python manage.py shell
```

This works for creating superusers, but not for updating them. Is there a way to automate the creation or update of superusers? Something similar to `create_or_update`.

Answer (score 1):

`User.objects.create_superuser` creates a user with `is_staff=True` and `is_superuser=True`. And [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) first checks if any row exists with the given arguments.

So you can create a superuser with the command your added. i.e.

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser(email='admin@myproject.com', password='password')" | python manage.py shell
```

and update that row with the following:

```
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.update_or_create(email='admin@myproject.com', is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, defaults={'username': 'abcd'})" | python manage.py shell
```

It will create new user with there is no record found with the given data.
You can further read about [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create).